Why rman doesnt' honor tags for some backups?
This is my script for backup using rman
#!/bin/bash

export ORA_OWNER=oracle
export ORACLE_VER=23ai
export ORACLE_BASE=/opt/oracle/app
export ORACLE_HOME=/opt/oracle/product/$ORACLE_VER/dbhomeFree
export ORACLE_SID=FREE
export ORACLE_HOME_LISTNER=$ORACLE_HOME
export TNS_ADMIN=/opt/oracle/product/$ORACLE_VER/dbhomeFree/network/admin
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin
export TAG='BACKUPUSERTB_'$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
backup tablespace users tag $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"

# DB ROOT

export TAG='ROOT_'$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
BACKUP DATABASE ROOT TAG $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"

# VIDEO PLUGDB
export TAG='VIDEO_'$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
BACKUP PLUGGABLE DATABASE video TAG $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"

# BOOKS plugdb
export TAG='BOOKS_'$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
BACKUP PLUGGABLE DATABASE books TAG $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"

#DATABASE
export TAG='DATABASEFULL'_$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
BACKUP DATABASE PLUS ARCHIVELOG TAG $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"


#ARCHIVELOG
export TAG='ARCHIVELOG'_$(date +%d%m%Y)

cat > backup.rcv <<EOF
run{
BACKUP ARCHIVELOG ALL TAG $TAG;
}
exit;
EOF

rman target / cmdfile=backup.rcv using "$TAG"
Let's see the results
rman
list backupset of database summary;


174     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         BACKUPUSERTB_27102024
176     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         ROOT_27102024
178     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         VIDEO_27102024
180     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         BOOKS_27102024
183     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         TAG20241027T055331
184     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         TAG20241027T055331
185     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         TAG20241027T055331
186     B  F  A DISK        27-OCT-24       1       1       NO         TAG20241027T055331

Userdb, root, video and book are perfect, why the other tags are not "followed"?
and appear TAG+timestamp?
